# How to centre 2 elements in a constraint layout, which have different heights

Tags: android, xml, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to centre elements in a constraint layout, I could use a guide line to be centred and then place the image and textview up and below it, but image and textview are of different height so they would not be centred.

any best approach on this please

```
         <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/noDataMessageLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/monthSpinner"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/monthlyChargeConsumptionLayout">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/noDataImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_data"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/noDataMessageTV"
                        style="@style/Text.Small.Light"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="No charge session data\navailable for this month."
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noDataImage" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it looks at the moment.

Thanks for your help in advance
R

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try applying same constraints for Both ImageView and TextView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/noDataMessageLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_horizontal_small"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/monthSpinner"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/monthlyChargeConsumptionLayout">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/noDataImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_data"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/noDataMessageTV"
                        style="@style/Text.Small.Light"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_vertical_small"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="No charge session data\navailable for this month."
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if i do this, will they not overlap over each other?

Comment: They will overlap, Can you attach the required design?

Answer (score 0):

This would be solved by using Chains in the ConstraintLayout

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
```

> a chain consists of multiple views, so to create a chain we must select the views we wish to chain together, and then select either ‘Center Horizontally’ to create a horizontal chain, or ‘Center Vertically’ to create a vertical chain.

example

[image: Create chains]

Source : [check this](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center two views regardless of the relative heights of the views you can place them into a vertical chain with a chain style of `packed` as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

You can also position them anywhere vertically by changing the vertical bias.

[image]